# .Net framework client profile issue

Tags: c#, .net, .net-client-profile

I have a C# project developed by someone else. When I open it in VS 2013 then it shows message that it is targeting .Net Framework 4.0 client profile which is not installed so either change target to 4.5 or install it 4.0.

I downloaded .Net framework 4.0 client profile and when tried to install it, got error message that a higher version is already available on the system.

How to fix this issue?

Here's the link from where I downloaded the file.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24872

Comment: Frank, why can't you simply change target to 4.5?

Comment: I can change but I am wondering why .Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile is missing from drop down menu.

Comment: I think the confusion is that when Microsoft introduced "client profile" with .Net 4.0 that in some contexts they just call it .Net 4.0, and don't mention the "client profile" part. The full version is always called "full version", but "client profile" often has no mention that is it in fact "client profile".